# Build failed with some exception in flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

suddenly while starting my app in visual studio code, i got the following lines as errors..

> Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1801 in debug mode...
>   * Error running Gradle:
>   ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\sanjay\demo\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
  Command: C:\Users\sanjay\demo\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)

can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: are you behind proxy or some network restriction?

Comment: Yeah it seems so

Answer (score 0):

I think this  version of gradle not supported just use an other version by changing class path in my case:

dependencies { 
classpath'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' }

Comment: i did,but that doesn't helped.

Comment: Use vpn if you in a country that has restriction and in build.gardle file put google() in top of jcenter() 
In my case it worked 
Sorry that all i know